# Offering Bounties on Blog Topics?

Tags: discussion, blog, bounty

Suppose I have a vested interest in seeing a blog post about a particular subject be written by a domain expert who may be reluctant to do it of their own volition. Would there be a good way of awarding a bounty on this to incentivize its completion? I find this somewhat ethically spurious but at the same time it might be a good way of awarding for difficult topics.

Comment: You could post a question asking for a blog post and put a bounty on it, and have the blog poster answer with a link to the post.  You could repeatedly bribe the mods to keep re-opening your question.